# java run jar with external manifest file

Tags: java, manifest, external

i am searching for a way to run a .jar file with the java compiler and without having the manifest inside of the jar.

Also it would be helpful, if the old manifest from the jar is getting ignored from the compiler in that process.

With that method i should be able to specify a custom Main-Class and a custom Class-Path.

Other methods are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

> i am searching for a way to run a .jar file with the java compiler and
>   without having the manifest inside of the jar.

You cannot run Java app with compiler, but you can do this in JRE with JVM

> Also it would be helpful, if the old manifest from the jar is getting
>   ignored from the compiler in that process.

Just dont include manifest in your build

> With that method i should be able to specify a custom Main-Class and a
>   custom Class-Path.

Its already doeable from CLI. Moreover, manifest was created so you DO NOT HAVE to do this from CLI.
But anyway

```
java -cp your/custom/class/path/here fully.qualified.name.of.Main
```

and you are done. Just remember to include your `JAR` file in classpath as well.